If we assume God exists, why isn't He doing something about all the wars and suffering on Earth? Is there a plan behind His reasoning?
Just so you know, I'm religious, I'm Christian. However, that doesn't stop me from wondering about this question. I'm sure someone must have asked a similar question before, so I'm sorry if I'm boring you with this... I'm not a university student or anything, nor do I have a degree (I'm a student), so I'm not like super good at this...
(sorry for only using wikipedia as a source, I know that's not very good...)
Existence of God Wikipedia
Problem of Evil Wikipedia
God Wikipedia

You already linked to the problem of evil - that deals with the question you're asking, and you can find plenty of takes about that from different sides on Wikipedia and elsewhere. An answer to this would basically be to just summarise the problem of evil, but that may be a bit broad for this site, or maybe not, but Wikipedia already provides that (and you've already linked to that, so I'm not sure what you're looking for here).

no, I'm saying IF God exists and assuming He does, why is there suffering, etc. That's my question. I'm basically just asking for anyone's theories... I mean, it is a discussion forum, after all...

The entire "theistic responses" section of the Wikipedia page on the problem of evil does exactly what you ask. That also links to an entire separate Wikipedia page on theistic responses. Theists consider God (or a god or gods) to exist, and tries to explain why there's suffering if God exists.

Welcome, but his isn't actually a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site.  FYI, there is also a Christianity Stack Exchange site that may be a better fit for a theological question like this.  That said, your question isn't a new one, and has been pretty thoroughly discussed over a couple millenia...

@QueenSophie: If you want a proper logical answer to this question, you can start by reading this, and ping me (by typing @user21820 in your message) afterwards for further discussion.

You assume you are separate from God.
What if you assume the contrary: You are part of the problem; you are part of the solution; you are in collaboration with God as co-creator?

I normally don't directly recommend it but in this case it may be good for you to look up non-duality.  The most accessible book I've seen on it is Illusions by Richard Bach.
